# Permutation Tree for Combinatorial Search Problems?

Tags: search, recursion, permutation, divide-and-conquer

I would like to generate a Search tree for a permutation problem. My requirement is as follows: I want to use a Divide and Conquer strategy for doing so

I am giving an example tree length 3 Permutation.

[image: Example tree for length 3 permutation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set of `n` numbers, divide the problem into `n` subproblems, each having one of the numbers from the set as the first number and the chosen number removed from the set. For each subproblem, repeat the process. If set is empty, stop.